# Multiple records taken in a Data Driven SoapUI test case with Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to copy multiple rows from an excel sheet with a Groovy Script, but somehow I am hitting the **java.lang.NullPointerException** error. The code I am using is the following:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder   

 import jxl.*   

 import jxl.write.*

def numofapps = context.expand('${Data_AppNM#NumberOfApplicants}')

 def apps2 = ["2","3","4","5","6"]

 def myTestCase = context.testCase   

 def counter,next,previous,size   

 Workbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C://Path//Multiple records.xls")) 

 Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet(0)   

 size= sheet1.getRows().toInteger()

 propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Data")    

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Total", size.toString())   

 counter = propTestStep.getPropertyValue("Count").toString()    

 counter = counter.toInteger()

 next = (counter > size-2? 0: counter+1)   



 Cell u1_1 = sheet1.getCell(0,counter)
 Cell u2_1 = sheet1.getCell(1,counter)
 Cell u3_1 = sheet1.getCell(2,counter) 

 workbook1.close()



 1value1 = u1_1.getContents()
 2value1 = u2_1.getContents()
 3value1 = u3_1.getContents()       

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A1.1Value", 1value1 ) 
 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A1.2Value", 2value1 )
 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A1.3Value", 3value1 )

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Count", next.toString())  

 next++ //increase next value   

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Next", next.toString())

if (apps2.contains(numofapps)){ //setting values for Applicant 2 if requested

 counter = propTestStep.getPropertyValue("Count").toString()    

 counter = counter.toInteger()

 next = (counter > size-2? 0: counter+1)

 // Extracting the Data from the Excel sheet   

 Cell u1_2 = sheet1.getCell(0,counter)
 Cell u2_2 = sheet1.getCell(1,counter)
 Cell u3_2 = sheet1.getCell(2,counter) 

 workbook1.close()


 1value2 = u1_2.getContents()
 2value2 = u2_2.getContents()
 3value2 = u3_2.getContents()

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A2.1Value", 1value2 )  
 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A2.2Value", 2value2 )
 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("A2.3Value", 3value2 )

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Count", next.toString())

 next++ //increase next value   

 propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Next", next.toString())

}
```

I am hitting the NullPointerException error on the `Cell u1_2 = sheet1.getCell(0,counter)` step.

Can you please tell me why I am hitting these and is there any other way that I can use a shorter code?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: seems you are closing workbook `workbook1.close()` before the line where you try to read from the sheet of this workbook.

Comment: @daggett - Yes, that was the problem after all, when I placed `workbook1.close()` at the end after all statements it worked correctly :) Thank you again :)